# Busboy file event not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, busboy

So, I have this post request which used to work fine but once I upgraded to Node 10 I can't seem to figure out why the file event completely stopped firing...

```
router.post('/uploadImage', authenticate.FBAuth, (req, res) => {
    const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });
    let imageFileName;
    let imageToBeUploaded = {};

    busboy.on('file', function onFile(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('onFile started');
        
        if (mimetype !== 'image/png' && mimetype !== 'image/jpeg') {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unsupported file format' });
        }

        const imageExtension = path.extname(filename);
        imageFileName = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000000)}.${imageExtension}`;
        console.log(imageFileName);

        const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
        console.log(filepath);

        imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
        console.log(imageToBeUploaded);

        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    });

    busboy.on('finish', function onFinish() {
        admin
            .storage()
            .bucket(config.storageBucket)
            .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
                resumable: false,
                metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
                    }
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                const imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media`;
                return db.doc(`/users/${req.user.handle}`).update({ imageUrl });
            })
            .then(() => {
                return res.json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: error.code });
            });
    });

    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
});
```

I tried to do `console.log(imageToBeUploaded);` inside onFinish and it is always an empty object. Besides, any console logs inside onFile never seem to print.

I also tried without authenticate.FBAuth middleware but that didn't make any difference.

This is the error from `bucket().upload()` basically complaining that the path is invalid which makes sense since `imageToBeUploaded` is an empty object and hence `imageToBeUploaded.filepath` is `undefined`

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:121:11)
    at Object.basename (path.js:1156:5)
    at Bucket.upload (/Users/mac/Dev/meows/server/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js:2493:38)
    at /Users/mac/Dev/meows/server/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:69:28
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bucket.wrapper (/Users/mac/Dev/meows/server/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:54:16)
    at Busboy.onFinish (/Users/mac/Dev/meows/server/routes/profileRouter.js:116:14)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Busboy.emit (/Users/mac/Dev/meows/server/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:37:33)
    at /Users/mac/Dev/meows/server/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:304:17 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I am using Postman for the test and choosing form-data for body and File for the input type. Made sure that Postman handled the Content-Type header setting it to `multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>`

Also, this is the file containing `authenticate.FBAuth` just in case

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = {
    FBAuth: (req, res, next) => {
        let idToken;
        if (req.headers.authorization == null || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('bearer ')) {
            console.log('Unrecognized token format');
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unauthorized operation' });
        }
        else {
            idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('bearer ')[1];
        }
        return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
            .then(decodedToken => {
                req.user = decodedToken;
                return db.collection('users')
                    .where('userId', '==', req.user.uid)
                    .limit(1)
                    .get()
                    .then(data => {
                        req.user.handle = data.docs[0].data().handle;
                        req.user.imageUrl = data.docs[0].data().imageUrl;
                        return next();
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error verifying token ', error);
                return res.status(403).json(error);
            });
    }
}
```

And here is `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "busboy": "^0.3.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.15.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "unirest": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it

The problem is that the code was migrated to docker from a cloud function. In the cloud function you use `busboy.end(req.rawBody)` since this is where the cloud function stores the request after consuming it. But after migration to docker the request is passed directly to the express route and `req.rawBody` is never populated. The solution is to just replace `busboy.end(req.rawBody)` with `req.pipe(busboy)`

Comment: When I used `busboy.end(req.rawBody)` it never fires the `busboy.on('finish' () {....})` event. Any ideas? With `req.pipe(busboy)` the `finish` event is firing, but not the `file` or `field` events. Can you help?

Comment: You are great... been stuck on this problem forever and this worked perfectly.

Comment: What are the differences between `busboy.end(req.rawBody)` vs. `req.pipe(busboy)`?